# Getting custom org-agenda with show entry text

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've tried to build custom agenda that show entry text but can't figure out.
Here is the example:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands 
  '(
("w" "Work"
 ((agenda ""
      (
       (org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/work.org")))
      )
  (alltodo ""
       ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Work todo items") (org-super-agenda-groups
                                  '((:auto-category t)))
        (org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/work.org")))
       )
  (agenda ""
      ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Work journal")
       (org-super-agenda-groups
        '(
          (:name "Work"
             :tag "work")

          ))
       (org-agenda-span 7)
       (org-agenda-entry-text-mode 't)
       (org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps 't)

       ;; it doesn't work
       (org-agenda-entry-text-mode 't)

       (org-agenda-time-grid 'nil)
       (org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/journal.org")))
      )
  )
 )
    ))
```

So I've tried to configure "Work journal" entry but it still doesn't show entry text for inactive-timestamps although I able to manually execute (org-agenda-entry-text-mode) command in agenda view and it displays me exactly what I want.

Comment: No need to quote `nil` and no need to quote `t` -- just plain old `nil` and `t` are sufficient.  If you do not find a satisfactory answer, then you may wish to consider adding something like `org-agenda-entry-text-mode` to the `org-agenda-finalize-hook`.

Comment: Once I set (org-agenda-entry-text-mode t)  it still doesn't work so  then I've added hook and now it appears for all agendas. Any suggestions how to execute only for specific agenda?

Comment: I have not tested this, but how about creating an arbitrary variable and using it like this: `(defvar nixorg_p nil "When non-nil, org-agenda-finalize-hook will call org-agenda-entry-text-mode.")` and `(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook (lambda () (when nixorg_p (org-agenda-entry-text-mode))))` and in your custom commands, replace `(org-agenda-entry-text-mode 't)` with `(nixorg_p t)`.